# SQL statement to take user input and grab columns from multiple tables that can be executed over and over

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on an SQL statement that can take continually take different parameters passed by a user, such as column names from multiple tables, and the user can tell the program how it wants the information ordered and then it comes back as a table with the user specified columns and ordered how they want it. Needs to be able to accept different parameters that different users input. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am using Access.

Comment: how / where do you give the user inputs? are you running the sql command from a different program?

Comment: There is a web page that uses ASP.net to connect to the database so the user would use the web page to input their parameters